手動だとIn番号が飛んでしまいます
いくつかのセルを手動（CTRL＋Enter、SHIFT＋Enter）で上から1つずつ実行すると、In番号が１，３，５・・のように1個ずつ飛びます。
カーネルを再起動してすべてのセルを実行する　など自動でやると、１，２，３のように連続した番号がふられます。
手動で飛んでしまうのはなぜでしょうか
Jupyter　Notebookのバージョンは7.0.8、Pythonは3.12.4　です。

その現象が起きるのは全てのnotebookですか？

これは複数のスクリーンショット等でどのような現象になっているかを段階を追って図で示した方が良いと思われます。ショートカットキーの説明記事はこんなものがあり、それらとどんな違いがあるのかも追記するとなお良いでしょう。Jupyter Notebookなどで最初に覚えておくと便利なショートカットキー, Jupyter Notebook ショートカット集, 【Google Colaboratory】作業が捗るショートカットキーを厳選して紹介！

「（CTRL＋Enter、SHIFT＋Enter）で上から1つずつ実行」とはどういう操作でしょうか？ セルごとに Ctrl+Enterで実行し, さらに Shift+enterで再実行してるなら, (2度ずつ実行しているので) 番号は飛び飛びになります。上から順に実行するなら, Shift+Enter繰り返すだけで大丈夫

ありがとうございます。
はい、すべてのNoteBookで同じ現象が起こっています。
「（CTRL＋Enter、SHIFT＋Enter）で上から1つずつ実行」ですが、わかりにくい書き方をしてしまいました。
CTRL＋Enter　で１つずつ実行していく、またはSHIFT＋Enterで１つずつ実行してみたのですが、やはり飛んでしまいます。
[1] a=10
[3] a-20
[3] -10
[5] a*30
[5] 300
このような感じです。
セルの間に別のものはありません。
カーネルを使うと
[1] a=10
[2] a-20
[2] -10
[3] a*30
[3] 300
このように連番になります。

訂正です。 手動だと１個ずつ飛ぶと書きましたが、セルを全選択してCTRL＋Enterを実行すると連番になります。 セルを１つずつ実行する場合にのみ１個ずつ飛んでしまいます。

手動時に, どういった操作を行っているか詳しく記すのがよいでしょう。例えば Ctrl+Enterでは別セルへの移動は行われないので順に実行はできません。マウス(あるいは何らかのポインティングデバイス)やメニューから何らかの操作を行ってるのでしょう。一つ一つの手順がわからないと推測でしか答えようがないので

CTRL＋Enterを行った後、タッチパッドで次のセルを選んで再びCTRL＋Enterで実行しています。SHIFT＋Enterでも同じ症状が起きます。自動で次のセルに移動したあと、ふたたびSHIFT＋Enterで実行しています。
